# omnibus installed chef and rvm issues

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ruby, chef

I'm trying to figure out one thing and would like someone's else view on this.
I installed chef on my Ubuntu server (11.10) via the awesome [omnibus install](http://www.opscode.com/blog/2012/06/29/omnibus-chef-packaging/). It worked perfectly fine. I was able to run chef-client and it ran without any problems.

Then I installed RVM and two rubies - and that's when my problems started. Straight after I installed RVM system wide ie by running:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```

And installed 2 rubies (setting one of the rubies as default ruby on the system) I couldn't run chef-client any more - I was getting "command not found" when run as normal regular user - I was thinking RVM messes some PATHS so that was the reason. I thought I'd run it as root ie:

```
sudo su -
chef-client
```

same result. Then I tried rvmsudo as it's being suggested by some people but that didn't help either. Then I gave it a last shot - I ran it as

```
sudo chef-client
```

And that's worked fine! I'm really puzzled as why is the above working and why is running chef -client as root (ie sudo su -; chef-client) NOT working. Am I missing something ? I'd really appreciate all the hints or explanations as I'm a bit lost. I'd like to run chef-client as a daemon as root and I can't do that with the sudo command above - I know I could set a user with nopasswd and it would probably work but I'd really like to understand what's going on here ;)

Comment: look at /etc/profile* for lines relatives to ruby/rvm and type "sudo env" and "sudo su - (new shell) env". Unfortunately i don't know chef

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having a path loading issue.

The omnibus installer installs Chef into `/opt/chef/bin/chef-client` and then symlinks to `/usr/bin/chef-client` [ref1](https://github.com/opscode/omnibus-chef/blob/master/package-scripts/chef/postinst#L96-L98) so that it's available to all users in `$PATH`.

The moment you install rvm it's going to mess with with $PATH, specifically, which ruby is to be used by Chef, since it's [loading the currently-running env's ruby](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/bin/chef-client#L1) when executing.

When running with `sudo su -`, you're changing to `root`'s environment, and running all of the associated profile/bashrc/bash_profile loaders that set up a user's environment.

When running with `sudo`, you're not loading the entire environment, so RVM won't be changing paths.

Another test you could to to see the impact of the shell differences is to run:

```
sudo which ruby
sudo su - which ruby
```

And compare the differences.

You might want to look at the [chef-client](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/chef-client) cookbook, which once executed, will help you set up a service daemon to control/config your chef-client service (we use this on all of our servers).

Since rvm is installed as default system-wide, then you may have to disable it for root (or the user you want to run Chef as, but I'd suggest root).

Comment: @gyre Never heard back on this one - did it help you solve the problem?